# Performance of delegate()

Tags: jquery, micro-optimization

I've been using `$("body").delegate(".selector", "click", function() { ... });` for a while now, and I was wondering: If I delegate the `click` event to a containing element closer to the actual element, for example a `table` full of buttons, would this be faster than delegating the same event to `body`, seeing as the event doesn't have to bubble as far?

Basic HTML example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Delegated element">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- More, identical rows -->
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

First example, using `body`:

```
$('body').delegate('input[type="button"]', 'click', function() {
    // Do things
});
```

Second example, using `table`:

```
$('table').delegate('input[type="button"]', 'click', function() {
    // Do things
});
```

Which of the two examples above is faster, and if one is faster than the other, *why*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I delegate the click event to a containing element closer to the actual element, for example a table full of buttons, would this be faster than delegating the same event to body, seeing as the event doesn't have to bubble as far?

Yes, it would be faster and precisely for the reason you suggest. I think [this](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) is a helpful article and fairly relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link. I thought things would work like this, but I was just curious as to whether I was correct or not. Also, happy 1K rep :-)